# error TS2307: Cannot find module 'app'

Tags: node.js, express, angular, typescript

I want to use typescript on node side. I have a very simple server. tsconfig.file inside my server folder is as follows:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "outDir": "../dist/serverBuild",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
 "exclude": [
   "../node_modules"
 ]
}
```

I have an app.ts file which has express related configuration in it and then I  have server.ts file which is importing app module from app.ts and it has code to create and start the node server.
But I am getting following error:

TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript
server.ts (11,22): Cannot find module 'app'. (2307)

other modules that I am importing in my server.ts file like http module is not throwing any such error. What am I doing wrong here.

Here is how I am importing modules:

```
import * as http  from "http";
import * as app from "app";
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load files from your project include the path. Use:

```
import * as app from './app';
```

By using `from 'app'` you are saying there is a module named app installed in your project. If that was the case you would need to install the typings for that module or create it yourself.